# Drawing rects on certain pixels openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying  to locate some regions of a frame, the frame is in Ycbcr color space. and I have to select those regions based on their Y values.

so I wrote this code:

```
Mat frame. ychannel;
VideoCapture cap(1);
int key =0;
int maxV , minV;
Point max, min;
while(key != 27){
     cap >> frame;
     cvtColor(frame,yframe,CV_RGB_YCrCb); // converting to YCbCr color space 
     extractChannel(yframe, yframe, 0); // extracting the Y channel 
     cv::minMaxLoc(yframe,&minV,&maxV,&min,&max);
     cv::threshold(outf,outf,(maxV-10),(maxV),CV_THRESH_TOZERO);
/**
Now I want to use :
cv::rectangle()
but I want to draw a rect around any pixel (see the picture bellow)that's higher than (maxV-10) 
and that during the streaming 
**/
     key = waitKey(1);
}
```

I draw this picture hopping that it helps to understand what I what to do .

[image]

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find the each of the [connected components](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contours#cv.FindContours), and draw their bounding box.

Comment: The link is to OpenCV's findContours() function. @Chris spelled it out.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have applied your threshold you will end up with a binary image containing a number of `connected components`, if you want to draw a rectangle around each component then you first need to detect those components.

The OpenCV function [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) does just that, pass it your binary image, and it will provide you with a vector of vectors of points which trace the boundary of each component in your image.

```
cv::Mat binaryImage;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;

cv::findContours(binaryImage, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Then all you need to do is find the [bounding rectangle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect) of each of those sets of points and draw them to your output image.

```
for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::Rect r = cv::boundingRect(contours.at(i));
    cv::rectangle(outputImage, r, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
}
```

Comment: thanks chris for your help, do you I can change the dimensions of the cv::boundingRect  ?

Comment: What do you mean change the dimensions? cv::boundingRect is a function that returns the minimum size rectangle than encloses the array of points which is passed as its argument. Once you have that rectangle (cv::Rect r in my example) you can do what you like with it.

Comment: Note that there are other similar functions (on the same page of the documentation) which fit other shapes to the set of points, including fitEllipse(), convexHull(), minAreaRect(), and minEnclosingCircle(). Have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) and find the most appropriate.